# How Reflection MakeUnion three level type?

Tags: f#

I want to try to reflect all types of combinations,

I am using a recursive function
Working at two level
But it won't work at the third level.

```ml
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let rec getAll<'A> (c : UnionCaseInfo) : obj [] =
     match c.GetFields() |> List.ofSeq with
                | [ x ] when FSharpType.IsUnion x.PropertyType ->
                        FSharpType.GetUnionCases(x.PropertyType)
                        |> Array.map (fun uc ->
                            FSharpValue.MakeUnion(c, getAll(uc)))
                        |> Array.ofSeq
                | _ ->
                  [| FSharpValue.MakeUnion(c, Array.empty) |]

type C = | C1 | C2

//type B = | B1 | B2
type B = | B1 of C | B2

type A =
    | A1
    | A2toB of B 
    | A3
    static member GetAll =
        FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<A>)
        |> Seq.collect getAll<A>
        |> Seq.cast<A>
        |> Array.ofSeq


(A2toB (B1 C1)).ToString()  |> printfn "%A"
A.GetAll |> Array.map (fun t -> t.ToString() |> printfn "%A")
```

```
"A2toB (B1 C1)"
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
```

when only use two levels 
`type B = | B1 | B2`

Correct return

```
"A1"
"A2toB B1"
"A2toB B2"
"A3"
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting the exception is that when you call `getAll` in the recursive case for `B1`, the field type is `C`, and `C` has two cases, `C1 | C2`, so you get back an array of two elements.  Then, that array is passed to the `MakeUnion` call for `B1`, which expects only one element (a single instance of `C`).  The call fails because there's an unexpected extra `C` passed in the array.

You can make this work for your example case by adding something like `Array.take 1` to your recursive call to `getAll`, but it won't work in the general case.  I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, so providing a general solution is currently a little tricky.  If you can clarify your requirements, we can probably provide a better solution.

Here's a version that works for your specific example (though as I said, this is not a good general solution):

```
let rec getAll<'A> (c : UnionCaseInfo) : obj [] =
     match c.GetFields() |> List.ofSeq with
                | [ x ] when FSharpType.IsUnion x.PropertyType ->
                        FSharpType.GetUnionCases(x.PropertyType)
                        |> Array.map (fun uc ->
                            FSharpValue.MakeUnion(c, getAll(uc) |> Array.take 1))
                        |> Array.ofSeq
                | _ ->
                  [| FSharpValue.MakeUnion(c, Array.empty) |]
```

Here's the output:

```
"A1"
"A2toB (B1 C1)"
"A2toB B2"
"A3"
```

Comment: Thank you, let me realize the recursive error, my expected result should be ["A1","A2toB (B1 C1)","A2toB (B1 C2)","A2toB B2","A3"]

Answer (score 1):

thanks Aaron M. Eshbach for found my recursive error, I fix my code

```ml
let rec getAll<'A> (c: UnionCaseInfo): obj [] =
     match c.GetFields() |> List.ofSeq with
                | [ x ] when FSharpType.IsUnion x.PropertyType ->
                        FSharpType.GetUnionCases(x.PropertyType)
                        |> Array.map (fun uc ->
                          let t = uc.Name
                          getAll (uc) |> Array.map (fun a ->
                              FSharpValue.MakeUnion(c, [| a |]))
                              )
                        |> Array.concat
                        |> Array.ofSeq
                | _ ->
                  let t = c.Name
                  [| FSharpValue.MakeUnion(c, Array.empty) |]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56782831) can be simplified. Let us reduce the level of nesting by one; utilize an array sequence expression for generation; and also, let's recurse on `System.Type` instead of on the unwieldy `UnionCaseInfo`.

The type parameter, removed below, could have been used at run-time only for unboxing the outermost union type. The type of the other generated cases is necessarily `obj`, also demonstrating the somewhat limited utility of dynamically generated union cases.

```
let rec getCases t = [|
    for ucinfo in FSharpType.GetUnionCases t do
        match ucinfo.GetFields() with
        | [|pinfo|] when FSharpType.IsUnion pinfo.PropertyType ->
            for x in getCases pinfo.PropertyType ->
                 FSharpValue.MakeUnion(ucinfo, [|x|])
        | _ -> yield FSharpValue.MakeUnion(ucinfo, [||]) |]
// val getCases : t:System.Type -> obj []

type A = A1 | A2toB of B | A3
and B = B1 of C | B2
and C = C1 | C2

getCases typeof<A> 
// val it : obj [] = [|A1; A2toB (B1 C1); A2toB (B1 C2); A2toB B2; A3|]
```